# Error parsing - Insert value Textbox inside database

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net

I have this form ASP.NET that have two textbox and a label, where the user enters only the expiration date in the last textbox, while the others are inserted automatically if the user clicks on another button inside the repeater where the customer code and company name are found.

The problem is that I created a class to do the insertion: I used a stored procedure for the insertion and I used the query parameterization.

When I parse the code and date it gives me 0 and a default date as a result, while my goal is to insert them into a table inside a db and then have it displayed inside the repeater.

P.S. I add that for reading the data I have another class with another stored procedure and that I have some values ​​that are inside another table (the code and the name of the company).

This is the method:

```vb
Public Sub INSERT_EXP_DATE_TABLE()

    Dim id_customer As Integer
    Dim exp_date As Date

    Try
        cmd.Connection = cn
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        MyParm = cmd.Parameters.Add("@COD_CUSTOMER", SqlDbType.Int)
        If (Integer.TryParse(txt_COD_CUSTOMER.Text, id_customer)) Then

            MyParm.Value = id_customer
        Else
            MsgBox("customer not found", vbCritical)
        End If

        MyParm = cmd.Parameters.Add("@COMPANY_NAME", SqlDbType.NVarChar)
        MyParm.Value = lbl_COMPANY_NAME.Text.ToString
        MyParm = cmd.Parameters.Add("@EXP_DATE", SqlDbType.Date)
        If (Date.TryParse(txt_EXP_DATE.Text, exp_date)) Then

            MyParm.Value = exp_date
        Else
            MsgBox("Exp Date not found", vbCritical)
        End If

        cmd.CommandText = "LST_INSERT_TABLE_01"
        cmd.Connection.Open()
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        MsgBox("Date registred", vbInformation)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)

    Finally
        cn.Close()
    End Try

End Sub
```

And this is the stored procedure:

```sql
@ID_CUSTOMER int,
@COMPANY_NAME varchar(50),
@EXP_DATE date, 

AS

BEGIN
INSERT INTO TABLE
                (
                ID_CUSTOMER,
                COMPANY_NAME,
                EXP_DATE,
                
                )

                
 VALUES(
 
 @ID_CUSTOMER,
 @COMPANY_NAME,
@EXP_DATE,
 
 
 )
END
```

Comment: Do you see any Error?

Comment: it says "cast no valide from string "" to 'Date' type

Comment: You are passing date as empty `MyParm = cmd.Parameters.Add("@EXP_DATE", SqlDbType.Date); MyParm.Value = exp_date`

Comment: which is the correct procedure? I try different parsing such as Tryparse and TryparseExact for date and Cint for integer.
It seems like it doesn't read the values ​​of the other fields, maybe it's a problem with the store procedure if the first two fields are from another table?

Comment: try this once `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EXP_DATE", exp_date); cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@COD_CUSTOMER", id_customer); cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@COMPANY_NAME", lbl_COMPANY_NAME.Text.ToString); `

Comment: Now give me another error: "SqlDateTime overflow. Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM."

Comment: can you check what is the date that you are passing to the procedure?

Comment: Give me 1/1/001 12:00:00 AM

Comment: Here you go then that is the error, from the error `SqlDateTime overflow. Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM."` it gives the date range. but you are passing `1/1/001 12:00:00 AM`, can you check why it is passing the Min date value. `1/1/001 12:00:00 AM` is the min date value in VB.Net/C#, when you declare a Date variable the value will be Min by default

Comment: Thanks, but now I have another problem I think in store procedure :                        
"Procedure or function except parameter which was not specified"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220908/discussion-between-sowmyadhar-gourishetty-and-camicode).

Answer (score 1):

Keep your connection local to the method where it is used. Connections use unmanaged resources so they include a `.Dispose` method which releases these resources. To ensure that the database objects are closed and disposed use `Using...End Using` blocks.

Do you parsing before you start creating database objects. Exit the sub so the user has a chance to correct the problem.

Side note: I don't think a message box will work in an asp.net application.

You set up the company name parameter as an `NVarChar` but your stored procedure declares it as a `VarChar`. Which is correct?

It is not necessary to call `.ToString` on a `.Text` property. A `.Text` property is already a `String`.

You are providing a parameter called `"@COD_CUSTOMER"` but your stored procedure does not have such parameter.

```
Public Sub INSERT_EXP_DATE_TABLE()
    Dim id_customer As Integer
    If Not Integer.TryParse(txt_COD_CUSTOMER.Text, id_customer) Then
        MsgBox("Please enter a valid number.", vbCritical)
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim exp_date As Date
    If Not Date.TryParse(txt_EXP_DATE.Text, exp_date) Then
        MsgBox("Please enter a valid date.")
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Using cn As New SqlConnection("Your connection string"),
                cmd As New SqlCommand("LST_INSERT_TABLE_01", cn)
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        With cmd.Parameters
            .Add("@ID_CUSTOMER", SqlDbType.Int).Value = id_customer
            .Add("@COMPANY_NAME", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = lbl_COMPANY_NAME.Text
            .Add("@EXP_DATE", SqlDbType.Date).Value = exp_date
        End With
        Try
            cn.Open()
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: can I use also this method for UPDATE?

Comment: You can use the same format for update but of course it would be a different stored procedure and a different set of parameters.

Comment: @CamiCode Who wrote the stored procedure?

Comment: Do you really have a table called TABLE?

Answer (score 0):

```
   {
       
       string CN = Interaction.InputBox("Enter Company Name","Customer","",-1,-1);
       string Cname =  Interaction.InputBox("Enter Customer Name", "Customer", "", -1, -1);
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=Adnan;Initial Catalog=Production;Integrated Security=True");
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO hello(Company_Name,Customer_name ) VALUES ( @Company_Name,@Customer_name )");
        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.Parameters.Clear();
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Company_Name", CN.ToString() );
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Customer_name", Cname.ToString());
    }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.